# Can not reorganize items in a position in Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla

I am developing a site with Joomla 3.0 using the default protostar template.
I am having issues with re-arranging modules published within the same position.

I have repositioned modules before within the same position (using the three vertical dots in module manager) and I am the super-user for the site.... so it might not be a permissions issue.

When I go to modules manager and filter-out just position 7, it gives me the modules in the position. I activate the three horizontal dots on the left that enable "repositioning" of modules. However, when I try to drag and drop(reposition) the modules, nothing happens. They behave as if locked in place.

Also, the three vertical dots have transformed into "i" symbols.

Any ideas on how to solve this puzzle?
Thanks folks.

Comment: I just tried it and it's working for me. Do you have the sort by ordering option selected (this should be true since you've activated the drag and drop, but I'm clutching at straws).

Comment: Yes I have sort by ordering...unfortunately my vertical dots are inverted single exclamation signs and I cannot reorder my items.